# Is it possible to steer the fischertechnik C64 robot interface via a modern USB port?

Tags: interface, usb, ttl, c64

I still have the fischertechnik computing interface 30566.
Is it possible to steer this interface via a modern USB port (instead of the C64 userport)?
I know there are adapters for turning USB into 5V TTL. Or do I need to have RS-232 in between?
And then?

Comment: I was curious of what it was and searched. The 30566 uses a parallel interface and not serial, so RS-232 will not work. Maybe a bi-directional parallell-port could work, but I'm not sure. I found a [project using an Audino](https://github.com/jacgoudsmit/Fishduino) that might be usefull.

Comment: Thanks, that might be the missing piece!